# how to write foreach loop for update query in mapper interface in mybatis

Tags: java, foreach, annotations, mybatis, ibatis

I have a update query in mapper interface using mybatis

```
 final String UPDATE ="update table_addresses "
                            + "set postCode= #{postCode}"
                            + "where id in"
                            + "<foreach item='item' index='index' 
                               collection='addressId' "
                            + "open='(' separator=',' close=')'>  #{item} 
                 </foreach>";
@Update(UPDATE)
public int updateInformation(@Param("postCode") String postCode , 
@Param("addressId") List<AddressID> addressId);
```

My AddressId class contains int type addressId:

```
AddressId {
private int addressId;
}
```

Now the method where I am calling mapper Interface..I am sending a String  postCode and object List addresses.

I am getting below error Caused by: org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'item' not found. Available parameters are [param1, param2, postCode, addressId]..What Ia m doing wrong here.What is the correct syntax of foreach loop where I can pass addressId which conatins List.

Answer (score 0):

For the complex sql statments. I prefer to use `SelectBuilder`/`UpdateBuilder`.

See the last part of this page [mybatis-java-api](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/java-api.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your whole SQL code in `<script>` tag like `String SQL = "<script>(SQL goes here)</script>"` if you use XML tags inside annotation defined query. Probably MyBatis doesn't see your #{item}, because it doesn't know about it (it treats all as SQL).

But, as Dean Xu sais, [sql builder](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/statement-builders.html) is better for more complicated queries.